# Xcode 15 beta error in GeneratedAssetSymbols

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode15

I am trying the new Xcode 15 and got some compile errors on the GeneratedAssetSymbols at ColorResource and ImageResource structs.

The errors are `Type 'ColorResource' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'` and `Type 'ColorResource' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`.

Someone knows what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having the same problem using Release Candidate (15A240d)

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I figure it out. It is because I have a class with the name Bundle. It is somehow conflicting with the Bundle used in GeneratedAssetSymbols. So, I have to rename my class to get it worked.

Posting here for helpless souls with the same problem.

Comment: if it's a problem specifically with KingFisher: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher. Use the xcode-15 branch